# How to add css to the mat-card background when mat-checkbox is checked which is inside the mat-card-content?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, parent-child, mat-card

I need to change the mat-card background color when the mat-checkbox is checked which is inside the `mat-card-content`

```
<mat-card class="checkboxselect text-center little-profile workspacetype">
    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-checkbox class="multipleselect"></mat-checkbox>
        <div class="workspacetypeimage">
            <i class="bgi bgi-certificate"></i>
        </div>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <h4 class="m-t-0 m-b-0 typetitle">Bidder Dashboard</h4>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: someone help me with the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There many ways to set the background. One of the ways that seems simple and comes to my mind is to use ngStyle, but you need to set an ngModel on the checkbox, or something similar so you can check its state:

```
<mat-card [ngStyle]="{'background': myModel? 'blue':'red'}" class="checkboxselect text-center little-profile workspacetype">
    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="myModel" class="multipleselect"></mat-checkbox>
        <div class="workspacetypeimage">
            <i class="bgi bgi-certificate"></i>
        </div>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <h4 class="m-t-0 m-b-0 typetitle">Bidder Dashboard</h4>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2qatha)

Comment: It can be set with ngClass, [class], ::ng-deep, in style.css, etc, etc... in case you need a class, not just color change

Comment: thanks. The above one is working. But I am using 20 check boxes. So i am writing this for all the check boxes. Is there any way to add in typescript as "if checkbox is checked" the mat card background needs to be changed.

Comment: Also the above one is working in check boxes. Also i need to add this for radio buttons. for radio buttons it is not working

Comment: please check in the above link(I have added screenshot)

Comment: You can have an array for the ngmodel, put everything in ngFo

Could you please give me an example

Comment: Here you go : stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2qatha-qurq9a –

Let me try the above one.
Thanks a lot

Comment: And i suppose to change icon for each card and mat card content also

Comment: If you just need to change color on click, no need for a checkbox or radio button, check out this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2qatha-gebkpz